# How can I use AJAX to submit data from a HTML form to a Google Sheet?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have create a form to submit and write the data to Google Sheets by following a tutorial. However, I have an error which says **ajax is not a function** No matter what I try I can't seem to get the .on click method to not cause this error & submit the data to the Google Sheet. Any help welcome.

```
    var $form = $('form#contact-test-form'),
    url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/MYGOOGLEDOCSHEET/exec'

    $('#submit-form').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var jqxhr = $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: $form.serializeObject()
        }).success(
            // do something
        );
    })
```

Comment: Do you have jQuery with ajax installed?

Comment: I am not sure about the title of your question VS the value you have in your `url` variable? Are you trying to run a macro programmatically using script.google.com or update a Google sheet directly through it's API? If you are attempting to access the Google sheets API programmatically I would suggest starting with the reference documentation for examples: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/writing

Comment: I have 3.5.1.min.js loaded then jquery.serialize-object.min.js I am following this tutorial https://medium.com/@dmccoy/how-to-submit-an-html-form-to-google-sheets-without-google-forms-b833952cc175